# Is it possible to get access to my skydrive personal files via sharepoint clientcontext?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, onedrive, office365

I have personal files in My Documents folder in SkyDrive Pro from Office 365.

As I understand, SkyDrive Pro uses SharePoint as backing storage. Can I access those files with SharePoint API (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContex)?

I mean SkyDrive Pro from Office 365. For example, if you go to the companyname.sharepoint.com, you will have menu in the right corner: Outlook, Calendar, People, Newsfeed, **SkyDrive**. And it is different from SkyDrive for consumers.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2013/08/13/access-skydrive-pro-using-the-sharepoint-2013-apis.aspx? It's about REST API, but they say "CSOM equivalents are available"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access files and folders information via ClientContext as usual. The only difference is that when constructing ClientContext, you need to use different URL – the one you see when you go to the "SkyDrive" tab (something like https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/username_companyname_onmicrosoft_com/).

If you want to retrieve this URL programmatically, you can use the following snippet:

```
 var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://**companyname**-my.sharepoint.com/");
 clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(**userName**, **password**);

 var props = peopleManager.GetMyProperties();

 clientContext.Load(props);            
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

 Console.WriteLine(props.PersonalUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn423226.aspx

```
    public static void GetSkyDriveFiles(string path, int rowLimit, string sortExpression)
    {
          string queryText = "Path:\""+path+"Documents/*\" IsDocument:1";    
          //string uriTempale = "{0}_api/search/query?querytext='{1}'&rowlimit={2}&sortlist='{3}'";
           var clientContext = new ClientContext(@path)
           {
                  Credentials = "ur credentials";
           }


           cxq.KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new cxq.KeywordQuery(clientContext);
           keywordQuery.QueryText = queryText;
           keywordQuery.RowLimit = rowLimit;
           cxq_ConvertSortExpressionToList(keywordQuery.SortList, sortExpression);
           //keywordQuery.SortList.Add("Write", cxq.SortDirection.Ascending);

           cxq.SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new cxq.SearchExecutor(clientContext);
           ClientResult<cxq.ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
           clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```